# Highchart jquery charts not working SetAttribute is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I have dynamically created a new div for each item in an array in my asp.net backend code. Each of these divs contain a unique ID, a class called boxplot, an attribute with the title of the highchart and finally an attribute that contains the chart data in JSON format.

I am trying to use javascript to retrieve the values in these attributes and create a box plot for each div dependent on the data in the attributes. Below is my javascript:

```
    $('.boxplot').each(function(i, obj) {     

        var desc = $(this).attr("graphdesc");
        console.log(desc);
        var gdata = $(this).attr("graphdata");
        console.log(gdata);


        var chart;
        var type = 'boxplot';
        var data = [JSON.parse(gdata).map(item => parseInt(item))]; //Doesnt work in IE



        $(function () {
            $(this).highcharts({
                chart: { type: type, inverted: true},
                title: { text: desc },
                //subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
                renderTo: this,
                legend: { enabled: false },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        pointWidth: 50
                    }
                },

                xAxis: {
                    visible: false

                },
                yAxis: {

                    visible: true,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Values'
                    },

                    plotLines: [{
                        value: hvtarget,
                        color: 'red',
                        width: 2

                    }]
                }
            });


            chart = $(this).highcharts();
            chart.addSeries({ data: data });

    });
```

I try and run this and I get the following error: jQuery.Deferred exception: k.setAttribute is not a function TypeError: k.setAttribute is not a function

How do i get these highchart box plots to display the graph based on the attribute values. What am i missing? Please advise if you need more information to be added.

Comment: Could you include an example for one such div element with all the attributes? It would make it a lot easier to troubleshoot this.

Comment: <div id=Chart0 class="pagebr boxplot" graphdesc="A Title" graphdata="[\"2\",\"16\",\"15\",\"16\",\"24\"]">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure for the graphdata cannot look like this:

```
<div id=Chart0 class="pagebr boxplot" graphdesc="A Title" graphdata="[\"2\",\"16\",\"15\",\"16\",\"24\"]">
```

It needs to look like this:

```
<div id=Chart0 class="pagebr boxplot" graphdesc="A Title" graphdata="[2, 16, 15, 16, 24]">
```

the lines where you use

```
$(this).highcharts({ 
chart = $(this).highcharts();
```

needs to reference the actual object you are iterating over, so they should look like this:

```
$(obj).highcharts({
chart = $(obj).highcharts();
```

```js
    $('.boxplot').each(function(i, obj) {
      var desc = $(this).attr("graphdesc");
      console.log(desc);
      var gdata = $(this).attr("graphdata");
      console.log(gdata);
      var chart;
      var type = 'boxplot';
      var data = [JSON.parse(gdata).map(item => parseInt(item))]; //Doesnt work in IE

      $(function() {
        $(obj).highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: type,
            inverted: true
          },
          title: {
            text: desc
          },
          //subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
          renderTo: this,
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },
          tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              pointWidth: 50
            }
          },
          xAxis: {
            visible: false
          },
          yAxis: {
            visible: true,
            title: {
              text: 'Values'
            },
            plotLines: [{
              value: 8,
              color: 'red',
              width: 2
            }]
          }
        });
        chart = $(obj).highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({
          data: data
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>


<div id=Chart0 class="pagebr boxplot" graphdesc="A Title" graphdata='[2, 16, 15, 16, 24]'>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/3skyaeq5/22/